# PVC Window swelling - problematic of not?

Tags: windows, pvc

In the fall, we had PVC windows installed in the house. The living room window frame is 4 meters (13 feet) long (schema below). The frame has a dark color on the outside. Now, the first sunny days came and I noticed that the frame swells exactly in the middle, under the big glass pane. the curvature happens only on the middle frame and it is 4mm (0.15in) at the middle, but there only mild sun now, so I expect it to grow much larger in the summer. Is this problematic? Can it affect the glass pane (which is very big and very heavy)?

[image: schema attached]
[image]

Comment: In the States, many people use PVC "wood" trim for the outside of the house. It only comes in white and it's not supposed to be painted (particularly dark colors) because it expands. I would suspect that this is going to become a bigger problem. I would get in touch with the company that made/installed this window and talk to them about this. I'm sure the window's got some sort of warranty, so you won't be out money if it fails, but it sure will be inconvenient! I don't know if it would actually break the glass, but it could easily leak.

Comment: "Swells" and "warps" are two very different things. Which is it? I suspect warping due to thermal expansion.